# Visual Web Part Property Validation in Sandbox Solution [SharePoint Online 2013]

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, visual-web-part, validation, custom-web-part-property

How can I validate a custom web part property in a Sandbox solution (SharePoint Online 2013 environment)?

I am throwing a `WebPartPageUserException` when validation fails, as shown below.

```
private string fileName = "test";

[WebBrowsable(true),
Category("Custom Properties"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebDisplayName("Template File Name")]
public string TemplateFileName
{
    get { return fileName; }
    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new WebPartPageUserException("Template File Name cannot be empty.");

        fileName = value;
    }
}
```

Throwing the `WebPartPageUserException` exception is breaking the web part; it starts displaying this error message:

**Web Part Error**: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred. Correlation ID: 1e535d9c-0f00-e011-b94d-8fb08e826bea.

**ULS** logs the below error:

```
SPNavigationNode previousSibling, PortalSiteMapNode parentNode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildrenInner(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.PopulateNavigationChildren(NodeTypes includedTypes)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.CreateRefreshedVersion(List`1& newObjects)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObjectFactory.ReSyncChangedCache()".
```

I thought the error might be related to the left navigation menu, so I tried removing it from the page (just in case). But this did not have any effect.

I have also tried deploying to several different environments and site collections, with no luck.

Can a `WebPartPageUserException` be thrown from a Sandbox solution?
If not, what is the suggested way for handling custom web part property validation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, this is not allowed from inside a sandboxed solution.

You're going to have to test the value some way or the other, and maybe render a message to the user inside the webpart itself.

Related question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47181/does-web-part-property-validation-only-work-for-visual-web-parts)

Comment: Thanks @Anima, I thought as much and had in fact seen that related question, but couldn't find anything on MSDN so I thought maybe someone had figured out how to use WebPartPageUserException in Sandbox. :(